# Kendo Reporting calling stored procedure multiple times

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using kendo reporting v 11.x. and MS SQL Server. I created a stored procedure that returns a list of person.
Then, I created a kendo report using visual studio. I selected a blank report and then I created a sqldatasource from the toolbox. I selected the stored procedure and then I created a table using the toolbox again and then I used data explorer dragged the field names to the name and one field outer.
[image]

When I click preview tab it's working as expected

[image]

But my stored procedure is being called multiple times sometimes 2 times, 3times, 4 times in the database depending on the number of fields in the forms.
I verified this my keeping an insert query in the procedure

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Test
    (
        [Name]
    )
    VALUES
    (
        'abc'  -- Name - varchar(50)
    )
   SELECT p.* FROM dbo.Person AS p
```

Each time I click the preview tab, there are multiple rows on the test table.
I tried using the latest 12.x version too but the issue is still present. This will definitely put the load on the database.